# Running Meteor on localhost fails with RangeError: port should be >= 0 and < 65536: NaN

Tags: mongodb, meteor, localhost

I am running a project on localhost using node and Mongodb, but it fails with an error as soon as I try to create a collection on the database.

I am building the project with this script:

```
cd ~/Meteor/daily-reminder
meteor build ~/build-output-daily-reminder --server=http://localhost
cd ~/build-output-daily-reminder
tar -xvzf daily-reminder.tar.gz
rm daily-reminder.tar.gz
cd ~/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle
(cd programs/server && npm install)
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://username:password@http://localhost:27017/daily-reminder'
export ROOT_URL='http://localhost/'
export PORT='3000'
echo "now run node main.js"
node main.js
```

(I use my actual mongodb username and password in the real code).

The project builds fine, but node won't run. It generates this error:

```
now run node main.js
/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
RangeError: port should be >= 0 and < 65536: NaN
    at Socket.connect (net.js:917:13)
    at Object.exports.connect.exports.createConnection (net.js:92:35)
    at [object Object].Connection.start (/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:173:29)
    at _connect (/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:211:16)
    at [object Object].ConnectionPool.start (/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:231:3)
    at Server.connect (/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:708:18)
    at Db.open (/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:281:23)
    at connectFunction (/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:275:67)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:345:5)
    at Function.Db.connect (/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/npm/mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:2094:23)
```

If I use a newly-created Meteor project then node runs ok. But it fails as soon as I add this line to start of my js file:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
```

It seems like there is some problem as soon as the server tries to communicate with the database. But I can't see anything wrong with my MONGO_URL: port is specified as 27017. From the error, it looks like the port isn't even being passed in.

I am using node v0.12.7 and MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9. I have started mongo by typing 'mongo' in a separate terminal window.

Comment: which shell are you running?

Comment: Update: if I use this MONGO_URL instead: 
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/daily-reminder' 
Then I get a different error: /home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
      throw(ex);
            ^
MongoError: auth fails
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/shelagh/build-output-daily-reminder/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
 I am pretty sure that I am using the correct username and password that I created when I installed mongo. But I don't know how to check this.

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MONGO_URL` is wrong, it redefines the protocol where you specify the host.

Change

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://username:password@http://localhost:27017/daily-reminder'
```

to

```
export MONGO_URL='mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/daily-reminder'
```

Comment: Cristian Fritz is right. I have it working now. 

It turns out that there was another thing I needed to fix also. The correct value for my setup is: 

export MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017/daily-reminder' 
I guess this is because I have just installed MongoDB and have not created any other users than the main administrator. 

I have learned: 

if you malform your MONGO_URL, node will exit with an error. 
if you haven't configured anything on your local mongo, don't put in any username and password.
Thank you very much for your help, it's very much appreciated.