# NodeJs Proxy Connection

Tags: javascript, node.js

why I cant connect with username and password with SOCKS5 like

username:password@ip:port, i can with HTTP, but cant with SOCKS5

doneusername:password@ip:port, i can with HTTP, but cant with SOCKS5

done

SOCKS5 ; username:password@ip:port

```
Attempting connection to ws://ip:port

Connecting to: ws://ip:port
net.js:928
      throw new RangeError('port should be >= 0 and < 65536: ' + port);
      ^

RangeError: port should be >= 0 and < 65536: NaN
    at lookupAndConnect (net.js:928:13)
    at Socket.connect (net.js:905:5)
    at Socket.connect (net.js:868:37)



var WebSocket = require('ws');
var valid_player_pos = null;
var reconnect = false;
var suicide_targets = null;
var socket = require('socket.io-client')(config.feederServer);

socket.on('pos', function(data) {
    valid_player_pos = data;
    //console.log(data);
});
socket.on('cmd', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.name == "split") {
        for (bot in bots) {
            bots[bot].client.split();
        }
    } else if (data.name == "eject") {
        for (bot in bots) {
            bots[bot].client.eject();
        }
    } else if (data.name == "connect_server") {
        if (data.ip == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (data.ip == "") {
            return;
        }
        for (bot in bots) {
            bots[bot].client.disconnect();
        }
        bots = {};
        game_server_ip = data.ip;
        console.log("client requested bots on: " + game_server_ip);
        setTimeout(function() {
            startFeederBotOnProxies();
        }, 1000);
    } else if(data.name == "reconnect_server") {
        reconnect = true;
        if (data.ip == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (data.ip == "") {
            return;
        }
        for (bot in bots) {
            bots[bot].client.disconnect();
        }
        bots = {};
        game_server_ip = data.ip;
        console.log("client requested bots on: " + game_server_ip);
    }
});

socket.on('force-login', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data == "server-booted-up") {
        return;
    }
    socket.emit("login", {
        "uuid": config.client_uuid,
        "type": "server"
    });
});

fs = require('fs');
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var Socks = require('socks');


function getRandomLine(filename) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var lines = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString().split("\n");
    line = lines[Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length)];
    return line
}

//object of bots
var bots = {};

bot_count = 0;

var fs = require('fs');
var lines = fs.readFileSync(config.proxies).toString().split("\n");
var url = require('url');
var game_server_ip = null;

function createAgent(ip,type) {

    data = ip.split(":");

    return new Socks.Agent({
            proxy: {
                ipaddress: data[0],
                port: parseInt(data[1]),
                type: parseInt(type)

            }}
    );
}

var proxy_mode = "HTTP";

function startFeederBotOnProxies() {

    for (proxy_line in lines) {

        if(lines[proxy_line].trim() == "#HTTP"){
            proxy_mode = "HTTP";
        }else if(lines[proxy_line].trim() == "#SOCKS4"){
            proxy_mode = "SOCKS4";
        }else if(lines[proxy_line].trim() == "#SOCKS5"){
            proxy_mode = "SOCKS5";
        }

        if (lines[proxy_line][0] == "#" || lines[proxy_line].length < 3) {
            continue;
        }

        //usefull for testing single proxies
        if (process.argv[3] != null && proxy_line != process.argv[3]) {
            continue;
        }

        proxy = "http://" + lines[proxy_line];
        proxy_single = lines[proxy_line];
        console.log(proxy_mode + " ; " + proxy_single);

        try {

            var opts = url.parse(proxy);

            if (proxy != null) {
                if(proxy_mode=="HTTP"){
                    agent = HttpsProxyAgent(opts);
                }else if(proxy_mode=="SOCKS4"){
                    agent = createAgent(lines[proxy_line],4);
                }else if(proxy_mode=="SOCKS5"){
                    agent = createAgent(lines[proxy_line],5);
                }

            } else {
                var agent = null;
            }

            if (lines[proxy_line] == "NOPROXY") {
                agent = null;
            }

            console.log("Attempting connection to " + game_server_ip);
            for (i = 0; i < config.botsPerIp; i++) {
                if(bot_count<config.maxBots){
                    bot_count++;
                    bots[bot_count] = new FeederBot(bot_count, agent, bot_count, game_server_ip);
                }
            }

        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error occured on startup: ' + e);
        }
    }
}

console.log("ogar-feeder-bot started! Join a game in Chrome with the Userscript installed.");
console.log("Press CTRL + C to stop this script.");
```

Comment: The error message says that your port is `NaN`. You might have made a mistake with the format.

Comment: Yes I think its cuz this format "username:password@ip:port" dont work for SOCKS5, because it works well for HTTP, but then I dont know how to log in to socks5 with username and password.

Comment: Maybe have a look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31416096/running-meteor-on-localhost-fails-with-rangeerror-port-should-be-0-and-655)?

Comment: Nothing, probably its the socket-io or socks module? or the main code... otherway, you know how to set up the username and password in the code?

Comment: You didn't show any code; there's just shell output. Could you edit your question and show the relevant part of your source?

Comment: Ok no problem, its already edited.

Comment: "ws://127.0.0.1:8081";

Answer (score 0):

From all of discussions I get that the problem with Your createAgent.

So use this code and be happy (:

```
function createAgent(connectionString, type) {

    var type = parseInt(type || 5);
    var ipParts = connectionString.split('@'); // splitting user:pass@host:port
    var host, port, username, password;

    switch(ipParts.length) {
      case 3 : // somebody@somewhere.com:somepassword@proxy.com:1080
        var credentials = (ipParts[0]+'@'+ipParts[1]).split(':'); // yusolokuji@leeching.net:luquitas
        username = credentials[0]; // somebody@somewhere.com
        password = credentials[1]; // somepassword
        var hostParts = ipParts[2].split(':'); // proxy.com:1080
        host = hostParts[0];
        port = hostParts[1] || 1080;
        break;

      case 2 : // somebody:somepassword@proxy.com:1080
        var credentials = ipParts[0].split(':'); // somebody:somepassword
        username = credentials[0]; // somebody
        password = credentials[1]; // somepassword
        var hostParts = ipParts[1].split(':'); // proxy.com:1080
        host = hostParts[0];
        port = hostParts[1] || 1080;
        break;

      case 1 : // proxy.com:1080
        ipParts = ipParts[0].split(':');
        host = ipParts[0];
        port = ipParts[1];
        break;
    }

    var config = {
      proxy: {
        ipaddress: host,
        port: parseInt(port),
        type: type
      }
    };

    if(type == 5) {
      config.proxy.authentication = {
        username: username,
        password: password
      };
    }

    if(type == 4) {
      config.proxy.user_id = username;
    }

    return new Socks.Agent(config);
}
```

Comment: Same error when I run the node, Could you add a specific username and password for proxies socks5 ???

Comment: check changes in my answer

Comment: It keep showing error when I put the proxy SOCKS5 as username:password@ip:port, I have for example 15 proxies SOCKS5 with the same user and password that I want to connect to, but i cant.

Comment: If You're working with sockets and etc, I thing You have enough experience to make if(){}else{} statements to check what is passed and etc. You've typed here question and waiting for full realization of Your code. Are You developer?!

Comment: Connection Failed: Error: Negotiation Error (authentication failed)

Dont connect, but the socks5 works well with the user and password

Comment: No i am not, but this code doesnt allow to connect socks5 with user and password or something

Comment: @L.Vi use this package, and live happy (:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-socks-client

Comment: No man!!! I'm not developer!! I dont even know how to code friend... I just have proxy/socks5 with authentication for this script and cant connect the socks5, that why I asked for help here...

Comment: I don't know how to use that, I have  differents HTTP/SOCKS5 that I want to connect, could you help me please?

Comment: Check my update to answer. You've not read docs of socks package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks

Comment: if it's not working, stackoverflow members will not help You, because You're asking us to make Your code work. if You need developer hands to help You, so go to: http://hackhands.com, http://freelancer.com and ask somebody to help You. Hope You're not angry about that. (:

Comment: You're right, but its not my code, I am just using it and as I wanted to connect SOCKS5 I noticed that I cant. Thanks for you answers, would you mind in accept me in skype? thanks.